# self-study problem: the behavior of conformal mapping at the Boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading Rudin's book, Real and Complex Analysis, and face a problem about the proof of Theorem 14.18. Here is my problem:

The hypothesis of the theorem is "$f$ is a conformal mapping of $\Omega$ onto $U$". However, in the proof, it seems that the author blindly assumed $f$ is one-to one, because he said "Let $g$ be the inverse of $f$".

I don't know why $f$ has a inverse, so I check the definition of conformal mappings. In the book, conformal mappings are defined as holomorphic functions with nonvanishing derivative. I know a one-to-one holomorphic function must have a nonvanishing derivative. However, nonvanishing derivative generally cannot imply a holomorphic function is one-to-one, but imply it is locally one-to-one.

Maybe it's a very stupid problem. Any explanations will be appreciated.

BTW: I've checked lots of textbooks relevant to the theorem. However, some books define confomal mappings as one-to one holomorphic functions with nonvanishing derivative. Others state $f$ is biholomorphic in the hypothesis of the theorem. Nothing is helpful for me to understand the theorem in Rudin's book.

Comment: Considering "one-to-one" to be a part of the definition of "conformal mapping from one region to another", even if not part of the definition of "conformal mapping", seems to be a cultural convention.  Or could that be an impression I somehow formed mistakenly?

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I think you raise a good point.  But as Y. Fan says, that convention conflicts with the actual definition that Rudin gives in the book, and he never mentions a switch to adopting the convention.  Therefore it is in my opinion an actual oversight, albeit an understandable and easily fixable one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One-to-one is supposed to be part of the hypothesis.  There are a few times in that section where "one-to-one" is intended but not stated.  This could be included in an errata list for the book if or when one exists.

Comment: So, do you actually mean that the so-called problem I mentioned is somewhat a little "bug" of Rudin's book?

Comment: Yes.-----------